# Is it possible to trade with villagers using some sort of score? (commands)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a system that transfers emeralds to a score to not take up inventory space, and that score can be used to trade. Is this possible? And if so, is it possible to display this score in the XP bar? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you can trade without taking inventory but try getting something you already have (Example: Wool) and spreading it in every empty space then wait for the items to despawn

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).